# Add rails image_tag in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I was wondering is there a way to add a rails image_tag dynamically with jQuery.

```
$(targetPlayerElement).html("<%= image_tag 'User.find_by_id(27).profile_picture'%>");
```

This is what i tried so far.

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$(targetPlayerElement).html('<%= image_tag User.find_by_id(27).profile_picture %>');
```

That must look like:

```
$(targetPlayerElement).html('<img src="src" alt="46" />')
```

If you get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` error in the console then is because the `image_tag` is inside double quotes, and the `src` of the `image_tag` will be also enclosed in double quotes.

There's no need to quote the result of `User.find_by_id(27).profile_picture` if it's a string, will be already quoted.

Which version of Rails? To use `find` instead `find_by_id`.

Also, use single quotes to enclose what `image_tag` prints.

Comment: Thanks for the help it generates the html code correctly but im getting a syntax error i cant figure out.     Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Because of the double quotes inside double quotes, I updated the answer agains that.